# rpmbuild debugsourcefiles.list is empty

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I am running rpmbuild (Fedora 38) to package my software and I got an issue while building debuginfo package. It seems that the find-debuginfo does not find the source files. The source tarball is in rpmtopdir/SOURCES and is extracted via `%setup -c <mysoftware>` in the `%prep` section. So, I got the sources in rpmtopdir/BUILD. The rpmbuild fails with this message:

> `erreur : Fichier %files vide rpmtopdir/BUILD/mysoft-8.19.0/debugsourcefiles.list`

I do not know how source files are searched from debug informations.